# Crontab cannot execute openstack's commands

Tags: shell, cron, openstack

I'm using Crontab execute CLI in Openstack, I create a shell script for execute all command.
My shell work when using ./ to execute in root

```
./myfile.sh
```

But:
when I using crontab it not working
Command of Crontab: in root

crontab -e

```
*/1 * * * *         ./myfile.sh
```

all commands in myfile.sh is working, BUT
Openstack CLI's Commands is not working

eg:in myfile.sh

1 echo "abc" > abc.txt

2 nova keypair-add --pub-key ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub key_1

3 echo "def" > def.txt

4 nova floating-ip-create ext_net

1 & 3 is work well, but
2 & 4 is not working

Comment: Add the full path of your script in the crontab line: `/home/user/.../myfile.sh`. Note that crontab runs with a very small environment, so you need to indicate full paths.

Comment: myfile.sh is working, but openstack's command not work

Comment: as @fedorqui said, you need full paths,either set your PATH to include the directories that nova lives in, or use the full path to nova in your script (Full path to script in crontab doesn't hurt either)

Comment: nova in root, fedorqui help me

Comment: nova in root as in /nova  or /root/nova ?  all you need to do is in your script is use the full path to the nova executable

Comment: @Doon myfile.sh is working, I think PATH is right

Comment: @Doon In terminal I using root@host# nova ... it working

Comment: On lines 2 & 4, change 'nova ....' to '/full/path/to/nova ...'

Comment: If you don't know the full path to nova, type "whereis nova" and it will tell you. Then use that on lines 2 & 4.

Comment: @markSetchell NOVA is working in root, I think needn't change PATH

Comment: You are missing the point! Cron doesn't go through root's login sequence - it has a different, minimal environment.

Comment: yes as @MarkSetchell Says Cron doesn't run a full interactive shell, it doesn't process path Statements. you can set the PATH that cron will use at the top of the CRONTAB, else use the full path to nova.  This is the only way it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenStack you probably should have an openrc.sh file avilable that you can retrieve from your openstack dashboard. This script needs to be active to be able to use those commands, and that is an issue with crontab, it won't have this script active even if you run it in rc.local. If you have the rc file available in your shell do the following steps.

1. Open your shell script
2. paste the following command on top of the script: source /Path/nameOfRC.sh
3. Thats it

I have had the exact same issue with my script, and this solution worked for me.